# How to fix the number of decimals to 500 digits output in Python?

Tags: python, string, floating-point, number-formatting, digits

In the following example:

```
import math
x = math.log(2)
print("{:.500f}".format(x))
```

I tried to get 500 digits output I get only **53** decimals output of **ln(2)** as follows:

`0.69314718055994528622676398299518041312694549560546875000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

How I can fix this problem?

Comment: Its not possibke, Please have a look at ieee754

Comment: Psylife, why the interest in a precise 500 digit result?

Comment: @chux, Because calculators don't bring it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the realm of real numbers, which is an infinite set of numbers with arbitrary precision, the floating point numbers are a small subset of numbers with a finite precision. They are the numbers that are represented by a linear combination of powers of two (See [Double Precision floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

As *Ln(2)* is not re-presentable as a floating-point number, a computer finds the nearest number by numerical approximations. In case of *Ln(2)*, this number is:

```
6243314768165359 * 2^-53 = 0.69314718055994528622676398299518041312694549560546875
```

If you need to do arbitrary precision arithmetic, you are required to make use of different computational methods. Various software packages exist that allow this. For Python, [MPmath](https://mpmath.org/) is fairly standard:

```
>>> from mpmath import *
>>> mp.dps = 500
>>> mp.pretty=True
>>> ln(2)
0.69314718055994530941723212145817656807550013436025525412068000949339362196969471560586332699641868754200148102057068573368552023575813055703267075163507596193072757082837143519030703862389167347112335011536449795523912047517268157493206515552473413952588295045300709532636664265410423915781495204374043038550080194417064167151864471283996817178454695702627163106454615025720740248163777338963855069526066834113727387372292895649354702576265209885969320196505855476470330679365443254763274495125040607
```

Comment: After the first line, it brings the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mpmath'. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: You have to install the module on your system. The way to do this depends on your OS.

Comment: It works with Python executable after I installed it [Thank you!], but with Python Shell when I put mp.pretty=true it brings the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    mp.pretty=true
NameError: name 'true' is not defined. How I can fix this problem?

Comment: True needs a capital T

Answer (score 2):

You can't with the Python `float` type. It's dependent on the underlying machine architecture, and in most cases you're limited to a double-precision float.

However, you can get higher precision with the `decimal` module:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
>>> getcontext().prec = 500
>>> d = Decimal(2)
>>> d.ln()
Decimal('0.69314718055994530941723212145817656807550013436025525412068000949339362196969471560586332699641868754200148102057068573368552023575813055703267075163507596193072757082837143519030703862389167347112335011536449795523912047517268157493206515552473413952588295045300709532636664265410423915781495204374043038550080194417064167151864471283996817178454695702627163106454615025720740248163777338963855069526066834113727387372292895649354702576265209885969320196505855476470330679365443254763274495125040607')
>>> print(d.ln())
0.69314718055994530941723212145817656807550013436025525412068000949339362196969471560586332699641868754200148102057068573368552023575813055703267075163507596193072757082837143519030703862389167347112335011536449795523912047517268157493206515552473413952588295045300709532636664265410423915781495204374043038550080194417064167151864471283996817178454695702627163106454615025720740248163777338963855069526066834113727387372292895649354702576265209885969320196505855476470330679365443254763274495125040607
```

Comment: How much of `0.6931...` is correct?

Comment: At least 100 digits. I'm trying to find another source.

Comment: [Online calc](https://keisan.casio.com/calculator) reports 130 digits:  "0.6931471805599453094172321214581765680755001343602552541206800094933936219696947156058633269964186875420014810205706857336855202358” matches all (rounded) and whose last 4 “2358” matches your answer's 2357_5813....

Comment: Your  digits 0.693...40607 matches [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=ln%5C%2840%292%5C%2841%29) ...40606_94381..., so looks good so far.

Comment: Thanks for checking - the only source I could find that doesn't actually perform the calculation is [numberworld.org](http://www.numberworld.org/digits/Log(2)/) but it only goes to 100 digits.

Comment: @sj95126 {from decimal import to ... d.ln()} it works in python 3.7 executable but it doesn't work in Python 3.7.0 Shell. But when I copy and past {from decimal to ... print(d.ln())} in Python Shell it works! Why Python executable doesn't compile with the same commands as Python Shell?

Comment: @Psylife: That I don't know, without more details. You may need to open a separate question for that issue.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: `Decimal.ln` should be correctly rounded. If you find cases where it isn't, that's a bug - please report!

Comment: @sj95126  I may start a new discussion later about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to get 500 digits output I get only 53 decimals output of ln(2) as follows:

The problem is not in the printing.  The 500 digit output *is* the exact value returned from `math.log(2)`.

The return value of `math.log(2)` is encoded using [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) which can only represent about 2<sup>64</sup> different finite values - each of them is a [dyadic rational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadic_rational).  Mathematically `log(2)` is an irrational number, thus it is impossible for `x` to encode the math result *exactly*.

Instead `math.log(2)` returns the nearest encodable value.
That value is *exactly* 0.6931471805599452862267639829951804131269454956054687500...

Printing binary64 with more than 17 significant digits typically does not add important value information.