# How to fix the ZeroDivisionError with 1000 decimals digits output in Python?

Tags: python, string, compiler-errors, digits, divide-by-zero

In the following [2 examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73439183/how-to-fix-the-number-of-decimals-to-500-digits-output-in-python/73450079?noredirect=1#comment129711749_73450079):

Example 1:

```
from decimal import Decimal, getcontext
getcontext().prec = 1000
d = Decimal(1+10**(-24))
1/d.ln()
```

Example 2:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps = 1000
mp.pretty=True
1/(ln(1+10**(-24)))
```

I get the `ZeroDivisionError`. `Python 3.7(64-bit)` takes it as `1/ln(1)` or `1/0`.

How I can make Python read it as `1/ln(1+10^(-24))` not `1/ln(1)`?

Comment: You need to *start* with the arbitrary-precision arithmetic library, not do half your calculation (`1+10**(-24)`) without it and then switch midway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- For example #1, make everything a `Decimal` resulting from operations between `Decimal`:

```
d = Decimal(1) + Decimal(10) ** Decimal(-24) # Decimal('1.000000000000000000000001')
Decimal(1) / d.ln()
```

otherwise you'd get a primitive type `float` precision first, and the number rounded to 1.0:

```
1+10**(-24) # 1.0
Decimal(1+10**(-24)) # 1
```

- Similarly, for example #2 (I just have read now the [docs](https://mpmath.org/doc/1.2.0/basics.html#number-types) for **mpmath**, so *take it with a grain of salt*):

```
from mpmath import mp, mpf, ln
    
mp.dps = 1000
mp.pretty = True
    
mpf(1) / ln(mpf(1) + mpf(10) ** mpf(-24))
```

Comment: You're still doing the `10**-24` computation in non-`Decimal` math.

Comment: Yes my blunder, I rushed to answer, thank you @user2357112. I have now fixed it.

Comment: @JonathanCiapetti The key is in d = +-/x^ Decimals(Xn). Thank you very much! for the first example. Any idea for the second example?

Comment: @Psylife the key is having always `Decimal` involved, also in the last operation: `Decimal(1) / d.ln()`.